# i is not defined for loop in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

Does anyone have any idea why i is not defined in this loop? i cannot figure it out...

I'm trying to paginate through the pages of data received from an api and gather it all into one array and store it in state, but my for loop doesn't seem to be working because of the error: "i is not defined"

how else should i go about this???

```
gatherAllCharacters = () => {
    fetch(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        let characters = data.results;
        const totalPages = data.info.pages;
        if (totalPages > 1) {
          for (i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            let page = i;
            fetch(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${i}`)
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(data => {
                characters = characters.concat(data.results);
                if (page === totalPages) {
                  this.setState({ allCharacters: characters });
                }
              });
          }
        } else {
          console.log("none");
        }
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a for loop like you have done above

```
 for (i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
     //perform loop
 }
```

However this generates a variable i in the global namespace and this is generally speaking a bad idea.

therefore you should initialise i before using it like so:

```
 for (let i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
     //perform loop
 }
```

Therefore ECMA decided to have a mode where this (and my other features that would cause undesirable side effects would instead throw an error).

see more here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

As your app is in use-strict mode it will be throwing the error "i is not defined"

Remember to initialize any variable before using it!

---

Couple things you should know about `let` and `var`

1. `var` and `let` can change their value and const cannot change its value
2. `var` can be **accessible anywhere in function** but `let` and `const` can only be **accessible inside the block where they are declared**.

Comment: I thought strict mode was NOT the default in React?

Answer (score 2):

Because i is not defined. You need a var or let in front of i to define a new variable.

```
for(let i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++ )
```

Comment: "Otherwise it places it in the global scope" if that was the case OP wouldn't get a `ReferenceError`

Answer (score 1):

```
- for (i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
+ for (let i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
```